# Compact width Window Air Conditioner

Tags: air-conditioning

we would like to install a window air conditioner in our living room window.

The window is quite narrow (18.5" wide). The room is fairly big, ~400sqft. We would like to install a 10000 BTU window AC unit.

I am looking at this Frigidaire AC, but I would like to know if this can be installed in this space.

http://www.walmart.com/ip/Frigidaire-AC-FRA103KT1-10-000-BTU-Slider-Casement-Air-Conditioner/15127187

[image: Picture1]
[image: Picture1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specs on the AC unit say it's 14.2" wide, so it will certainly fit in the opening. You don't say how high the window is, but if it's a double hung, two pane, slide-up window like the ones on the building across the way, you might have to remove the window to make this work then fit a glass or plexiglass pane into the space above the air conditioner after it's mounted. And be sure not to drop that thing in the street...  ;-)

**EDIT:** Typically, units like this rely on the top sliding pane of the window to hold them in the opening. The AC unit is heavy, and it will want to tip backwards out of the window. You can see the tab/rail along the top of the AC unit in the picture just below. If you drop the sash down behind that, it will hold the AC unit in place, as it can't topple out of the window.

So; typically, you would pop the front cover off the AC unit, then screw the bottom of the unit to the window sill so it can't slide forward out of the opening. Then drop the sash behind that rail and screw it to the sash. Otherwise, it would be possible for the sash to move up and allow the air conditioner to topple out of the window, which would ruin the air conditioner and could also maim or kill somebody below.

In your case, if the unit won't fit in the bottom pane and you have to remove the window, you'll need to secure (and secure it well) some kind of support across the window opening to replace the window sash you removed, so the AC unit can rest against it. And you'll still screw that rail to the cross support to ensure that everything stays in place.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  It is a "double hung, two pane, slide-up" window.Could you explain why I would need to fit a glass pane in the space above ?

Comment: @Abhijith I figured you would want to fit a glass or plexiglass (plastic) pane above the AC just to let some light in. The AC unit isn't going to fill the whole space, so you'll need to cover it with *something*.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you look up the [user manual / installation instructions](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/241071/Frigidaire-Fra103kt1.html) for that model it looks like your window might actually be *too wide*. This model is designed for casement and sliding windows with an opening width between 15 1/2" and 16 1/4", and a height of 21 1/2" to 40" (or up to 62" high with an optional accessory kit). I would not attempt to install the unit in a window that is the wrong size, especially since it looks like you are several stories up.

It's unclear from the photo what kind of window you have, but you might look at [portable ACs](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Heating-Venting-Cooling-Air-Conditioners-Coolers-Air-Conditioners-Portable-Air-Conditioners/N-5yc1vZc4m4) which sit inside the room and have a n exhaust duct going to the window. They are generally a little less efficient and take up floorspace, but they are somewhat more flexible with window size / layout.

Comment: The 6.5" width thing is almost certainly just because of whatever they use to fill the gaps on the sides (usually that fan-fold business). The caveat may be the weight of the unit vs. the bottom sash of most double-hung windows. I'd secure something strong into that window opening (like a 2x4) to rest the top lip of the AC unit against. I'd install that 2x4 very securely, using screws into the window frame. I would not just toe-nail it in. I'd secure blocked behind it (toward the outside of the building), screwed straight into the frame, butt the 2x4 against that and use plenty of screws.

Comment: Having said all of that; there may also be a local municipal code or something in your rent/lease contract about AC units and liability and so on. I'd check into all of that before installing anything.

Comment: @Craig: I'm not really sure how this model attaches so I won't speculate about whether the width is a critical measurement, but the manual says there is less than 2" of flexibility in the opening (15 1/2" to 16 1/4") so I doubt they are referring to a fan-fold panel.

Comment: Fair enough. But you could also frame the opening in smaller if necessary. a 2x4 screwed into the window frame on both sides would reduce the opening to 15.5"--right on spec. :-)